# How to check condition in a query.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `fdone, incident_one.`

**fdone** contains four coloums.

```
 INC_KEY,LAT,LONG,FDID.
```

**incident_one** contains `five` coloums.

```
INC_KEY,LAT,LONG,STATE,FDID.
```

i making the **fdone** table LAT LONG two as four by this query.

```
SELECT S.`LAT `,S.`LONG `,(S.`LAT `+5)as x,(S.`LONG `-5)as Y FROM `fdheader` S
```

and then i get as

LAT,LONG,X,Y

and then by using join query.

i have to check as,

incident_one LAT AND LONG is inside LAT,LONG,X,Y.

i have to check as..,

```
S.LAT<LAT ,S.LONG<LONG,X>LONG,Y<LONG.
```

i have to check this condition by sql statement.

shall u help me for join query.

i need this needful help for join query.

```
join  using FDID
```

thanks in advances..,

Comment: Are you just saying you want to inner join your two tables? Sorry, I'm not really following, not sure if it's the language barrier or the formatting.

Comment: can you please give me more explain . :)

Comment: i have to join the two table by using FDID coloum name.

Comment: and in where condition i have to check this condition as.,

Comment: S.LAT<LAT and S.LONG<LONG and X>LONG and Y<LONG.

Answer (score 2):

may be it's help for you

```
SELECT * FROM fdone fd INNER JOIN incident_one io ON fd.FDID=io.FDID WHERE io.LATE IN (fd.LATE-5,fd.LATE) 
AND io.LONG IN (fd.LONG-5,fd.LONG) ;
```